# Using 'salt.module.tomcat' for deploying war file

Tags: salt-stack, devops

I am trying to deploy war file using salt module `tomcat.deploy_war` but get following error ... 'KeyError' seems like it doesn't recognize `tomcat.deploy_war`

[image]

Talking of sls file, the module `file.managed` worked fine

[image]

Seems like I will need to upgrade my salt master and version.
Tried doing the same, got response that it's already upgraded.

Not sure what is the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tomcat.deploy_war` is an **execution module**, not a **state module**. In general, execution modules like `tomcat.deploy_war` are always named imperatively (*"deploy!"*, *"delete!"*, *"install!"*). You cannot use execution modules in states directly; instead, they are intended to be used in ad-hoc Salt commands, for example to quickly deploy a WAR file using a command-line statement:

```
salt 'tomcatminion' tomcat.deploy_war salt://path/to/app.war
```

On the other hand *state modules* are intended to be used in states and are named declaratively (by the desired end state). In many cases, an execution module has a corresponding state module -- in your case `tomcat.deploy_war` and `tomcat.war_deployed` (or `pkg.install` and `pkg.installed` and so on):

```
sample.war:
  tomcat.war_deployed:
    - war: salt://path/to/app.war
```

See the respective documentations for the [`salt.modules.tomcat` execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.tomcat.html) and the [`salt.states.tomcat` state module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.tomcat.html#salt.states.tomcat.war_deployed).

Comment: Thanks it worked , facing another issue ...          ID: deploy_war
    Function: tomcat.war_deployed
        Name: /order-management
      Result: False
     Comment: FAIL - could not cache the WAR file